# How to execute two operations one after the other in parallel using ExecutorService in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I am trying to execute two operations "printA()" and "printB()" in parallel. The condition being that printB() should execute only after printA() is executed for a Thread.
Below is my code, but it is not working as expected.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
        CountDownLatch countDownLatch = new CountDownLatch(5);
        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
            executorService.execute(
                    () -> {
                        printA(executorService);
                        printB(executorService);
                        countDownLatch.countDown();
                    }
            );
        }
        countDownLatch.await();
        executorService.shutdown();
        try {
            if (!executorService.awaitTermination(60000, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
                executorService.shutdownNow();
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

```
private static void printB(ExecutorService executorService) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            executorService.execute(
                    () -> {
                        System.out.println("B");
                    }
            );
        }
    }

    private static void printA(ExecutorService executorService) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            executorService.execute(
                    () -> {
                        System.out.println("A");
                    }
            );
        }
    }
```

Comment: "One after the other" means _not_ in parallel. "Parallel" means _not_ one after the other.

Comment: Just call directly `System.out.println("A");` instead of calling `printA` which actually doesn't print, but schedules a task to an executor. Similar for printing B

Comment: Your main thread shuts the executor down without first waiting for all of the `println` calls to be performed. I'm _guessing_ that might not be what you wanted to do. @gdomo's comment is just a guess too. You haven't told us what you want the program to do. What did you expect the program to do? (I.E., what did you expect it to print out?) What did it do instead? (What did it actually print out?)

Comment: “*but it is not working as expected*” is not a problem description. We do not know what you expected.

Comment: @SolomonSlow What I mean to say is that I want to invoke printA() and printB() together in parallel the condition being, that printA() should execute first and then printB(). So in the loop, 5 threads should start in parallel and invoke printA() and printB()

Comment: Once again, 'in parallel' and 'execute first' are mutually exclusive. If you just want to execute two print methods sequentially, you don't need threads and executors at all. Unclear what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to invoke printA() and printB() together in parallel the condition being, that printA() should execute first and then printB(). So in the loop, 5 threads should start in parallel and invoke printA() and printB()

Not 100% certain, but I *think* you are saying that you want five threads all to `printA()`, and then after they've all finished that, *only* after they've all finished, you want them to `printB()`. Is that right? If so, then you probably want a [`CyclicBarrier`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html).

If you create `CyclicBarrier barrier = new CyclicBarrier(5)` somewhere in your main thread, then you can create five "worker" threads that each do this:

```java
printA();
barrier.await();
printB();
```

The `await()` call will not return in any of the first four threads to reach it until the fifth thread enters it. Only then will it return in all five threads. That guarantees that none of the threads will `printB()` until all of them have done `printA()`.